# how to use not exists clause while filtering child records

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have Order and OrderSubscription tables.the relation between the tables is one-many.I am using oracle 11g.
I want to find out those orders where all of the OrderSubscriptions should be Expired but should have Active  Orders.

So final result should be
order id =1 and order id =4 records..

tried below query.Or Is there any other way to filter the records?

```
select * from order ord where
ord.order_status='Active'
and not exists(select 'x' from OrderSubscription os where ord.id=os.order_id and subs_status='Expired')

************************************************************************************

insert into Order(id,order_numbr,order_status) (1,12345,'Active')   

insert into OrderSubscription(id,order_id,subs_name,subs_status) (1,1,'360 fhf','Expired')   
insert into OrderSubscription(id,order_id,subs_name,subs_status) (2,1,'720 cef','Expired') 



insert into Order(id,order_numbr,order_status) (2,5757575,'Active')   

insert into OrderSubscription(id,order_id,subs_name,subs_status) (1,2,'360 fhf','Active')   
insert into OrderSubscription(id,order_id,subs_name,subs_status) (2,2,'720 cef','Expired') 
insert into OrderSubscription(id,order_id,subs_name,subs_status) (3,2,'540 abc','Expired') 


insert into Order(id,order_numbr,order_status) (3,979797979,'Active')   

insert into OrderSubscription(id,order_id,subs_name,subs_status) (1,3,'360 fhf','Expired')   
insert into OrderSubscription(id,order_id,subs_name,subs_status) (2,3,'720 cef','Expired') 
insert into OrderSubscription(id,order_id,subs_name,subs_status) (3,3,'120 juh','Pending') 
insert into OrderSubscription(id,order_id,subs_name,subs_status) (4,3,'60 ert','Active')


insert into Order(id,order_numbr,order_status) (4,3131313133,'Active')   

insert into OrderSubscription(id,order_id,subs_name,subs_status) (1,4,'360 fhf','Expired')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be one option: check whether the only status is "Expired" and fetch only those order IDs (if they are "Active").

```
SQL> with os as
  2    (select order_id, min(subs_status) minstatus, max(subs_status) maxstatus
  3     from ordersubscription
  4     group by order_id
  5    )
  6  select t.id
  7  from torder t join os o on o.order_id = t.id
  8  where t.order_status = 'Active'
  9    and o.minstatus = o.maxstatus
 10    and o.minstatus = 'Expired';

        ID
----------
         1
         4

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS` with aggregation comparison with `HAVING` Clause within the subquery in order to check out whether count of all `Expired` status along with all rows per each group of `order_id` values :

```
SELECT *
  FROM orders o
 WHERE o.order_status = 'Active'
   AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM OrderSubscription os
                WHERE os.order_id = o.id
                GROUP BY os.order_id
               HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN os.subs_status = 'Expired' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                    = COUNT(os.id))
```

where the table name `order` is replaced with `orders` as `order` being a reserved keyword.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3bdc4fafb3afadaa226f0f7886b7c6db)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question the query you want is:

```
select ord.*
from order ord
where ord.order_status = 'Active' and
      not exists (select 'x'
                  from OrderSubscription os
                  where ord.id = os.order_id and
                        subs_status = 'Active'
                 );
```

With an index on `OrderSubscription(order_id, subs_status)`, this probably has the best performance of any alternative formulations of the logic.